# How to install node dependencies if they are not available Gulp + nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, dependencies, package.json

I am using Gulp to start a web application. I have the following basic code for my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  nodemon({
    script: 'server.js'
  , ext: 'js html'
  , env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' }
  })
})
```

Using Gulp, I want to check for dependencies and if they are not available then install them and then run 'script.js'. How can this be done?

I have the following package.json:

```
{
"name": "sample-project",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Displays users and user details",
"main": "server.js",
"dependencies": {
"jquery"  : “>=1.5.1",
“bootstrap”: ">= 3.0.0”
}
"directories": {
"test": "test"
},
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "node server.js"
},
"author": "Arihant Jain",
"license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Can you add more gulp dependencies? There's `gulp-install` which claims to let you "Automatically install npm, bower, tsd, and pip packages/dependencies if the relative configurations are found in the gulp file stream respectively". I've never used it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can run **npm install** independently from an executing task using node's [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) as such:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var child_process = require('child_process');

gulp.task('default', function () {

    // Run npm install from the child process
    child_process.exe('npm install', function(err, stdout, stderr){

        // if everything goes well
        if(!err){

             // run nodemon
              nodemon({
                script: 'server.js'
              , ext: 'js html'
              , env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' }
              })

        }

    });
})
```

---

Given your requirement:

> Using Gulp, I want to check for dependencies and if they are not
>   available then install them...

That is exactly what **npm install** does. It checks the local **package.json** and proceeds to install missing packages.

Answer (score 0):

So, I worked it around in a way by using gulp-run. I actually run the command *npm install*.

gulpfile looks like this:

```
        var gulp = require('gulp'),
        nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon')
        run = require('gulp-run')
        runSequence = require('run-sequence')
        open = require('gulp-open');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  runSequence('dependencies',
              'start',
              'uri');
});


      gulp.task('dependencies', function() {
  return run('npm install').exec();
})

    gulp.task('uri', function(){
  gulp.src(__filename)
  .pipe(open({uri: 'http://localhost:3000/index.html'}));
});



    gulp.task('start', function () {
  nodemon({
    script: 'server.js'
  , ext: 'js html'
  , env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' }
  })
})
```